# IntelliJ advice using multiple maven projects at once

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I am a long time Eclipse user trying to migrate over to IntelliJ. Most everything feels superior IntelliJ bur I have hard time adjusting it to our maven setup.

Eclipse is workspace based. You can just import a bunch of dependency related maven SNAPSHOT projects and it automatically handles the rest. Namely when you application is spread over many maven projects, in eclipse, you can search/navigate seamlessly and the code changes propagate over the workspace immediately.

In IntelliJ you seem to only can checkout one maven project at a time. This way I end up having a lot of separate windows for all the different maven SNAPSHOTS the application requires. Therefore the search/navigate functionality is a bit lost and code change propagation requires command line "mvn clean install"/"triggering jar swapping" hell.

I don't expect everything to be superior to Eclipse and I can deal with losing some of the functionality when migrating since there a lot of good things in IntelliJ, but maybe there is something I am missing. Is there maybe a sensible way to achieve the same things IntelliJ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add multiple projects in the same window / workspace in IntelliJ as well. You can just click the '+' icon in the 'Maven Projects' window and choose the additional pom file for the module you want to add.

Comment: You just made my day. This does exactly the thing I need. Thanks!