# IntelliJ Community with 2 maven projects in same window

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven project `project-a` and `project-b` wo depends on `project-a`.

How can I work with this 2 projects in same IntelliJ window?

I want to be able to make changes on `project-a` and reflect them to `project-b` without deploy/install the `project-a`. I already do this on Eclipse using `m2e` plugin.

**EDITIED**

After setting the **Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing >> Import Maven projects automatically** the IDE was able to build part of my projects.

Now I'm facing another problem. This `project-a` has a dependency to`hibernate-entitymanager` who has a dependency to `hibernate-core` who has a dependency to`hibernate-jpa-2.1-api`.

My project  uses some classes from this `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api` jar, but seems that the IntelliJ can not resolve sub-dependencies, forcing me to redeclare this dependency (`hibernate-jpa-2.1-api`) on the`project-a / pom.xml`. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: I just have two tabs up with the different projects, which seems to work

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/eclipse.html (use modules).

Comment: The equivalent of Eclipse workspace is IntelliJ project, and Eclipse project is IntelliJ module.

Comment: @Tome I already configured my "workspace" using modules, but the IntelliJ seems not to be able to resolve the dependencies to compile the projects using CTRL+F9

Comment: My personal IntelliJ usage is based around creating an empty project and (via the _Maven projects_ tool window for instance), import Maven modules as IntelliJ modules. That way, when IntelliJ recognizes that `project-a` is present in the same project, with the same coordinates as the dependency in `project-b`, it will link as modules instead of using the repository JAR. Other ways of creating projects in IntelliJ will work fine with this too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ advice using multiple maven projects at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463980/intellij-advice-using-multiple-maven-projects-at-once)

Answer (score 2):

You should add you maven projects as modules to Intellij IDEA as already said CrazyCoder.

And then do  `'Add As Maven Project'` by right click on the every module's `pom.xml` in the Project tab.
This way you will be able to use cross-module searches, refactorings etc. Compilation will also be performed against the added Maven Projects without a need to install artifacts into the repository.